# CentOS: delete X-days old files using cron

Tags: linux, cron, find

I want to delete x-days old `.tar` & `.sql` files using cronjob.

I have tried multiple commands but it didn't work.

command such as,

```
find /path/to/files -type f -mtime +10 -delete
find /path/to/folder -name '*.sql' -mtime +30 -delete
find "$FILEDIR" -mtime +14 -delete
[[ $FILEDIR == /home/abc/* ]] && find "$FILEDIR" -mtime +14 -delete
```

above commands run perfectly but not deleting anything.
Need help.

Comment: The first one should work:

    find /path/to/files -type f -mtime +10 -delete

If it doesn't, do you definitely have write access to the files and execution permissions on all parent directories of the files in question for the user which is executing the cron? Do you have any cron output?

Comment: I have created `.tar` files in same directory using cron. So write access is there.

Comment: That's the same directory but have you tried deleting the actual files themselves? Add to your cron "> /your/log/file.log 2>&1" to have a look at what errors are getting printed. Also add -print to your find command to get it to print all matches found and have a look at your log to analyse. Your command itself should be sound though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use for loops and echo statements for debugging purposes and also to make sure I don't delete anything by mistake.

So try this:

```
for filename in `find /path/to/files -type f -mtime +10`; do echo "rm $filename"; done
```

That will list out what it plans to do.  Check it, make sure it looks good, then run by removing the echo statement

```
for filename in `find /path/to/files -type f -mtime +10`; do rm $filename; done
```

If it doesn't work, then you can output the above to a file and run it as a script

```
for filename in `find /path/to/files -type f -mtime +10`; do echo "rm $filename"; done > myremove.sh
```

Then run it

```
sh -x ./myremove.sh
```

And check the output above for errors.

Once you got it bug free, you can add to cron as a single command or in a script

Comment: `for filename in `find /path/to/files -type f -mtime +10`; do echo "rm $filename"; done` command is running perfect, but again output nothing

Comment: Type in the command "find /path/to/files" -type f -mtime +10" - is there any output? It's possible you do not have any candidate files e.g. files modified more than 10 days ago